# Method invocation ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); may produce NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I see that ActionBarActivity is deprecated.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        // Put the home button as an icon, without being an 'up' button and without title text
        ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.template, menu); // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        // tell the main activities view pager to enable paging
        mViewPagerListener.SetViewPagerPagingEnabled(true);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

What should I be doing today instead? I'm personally not seeing the exception while testing on my device, but would like to resolve this for completion. It's highlighted yellow in AndroidStudio and returns the warning. What should I do?

**Build for reference:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //runProguard false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.5.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.antonyt:InfiniteViewPager:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    // recyclerview
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    // google analytics
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    // pager sliding strip
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    // http library (for using beanstream REST)
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    // amaazon S3 uploads
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.1.+'
    // paypal purchasing
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.7.1.jar')
    // Module dependency on ParseLoginUI library sources
    compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
    // Parse libs
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
    // android support v4
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    // facebook SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    //butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    // Subsampling-scale-image-view (for templating)
    //compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.4'
    compile files('libs/AppRater.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated since ~1 year now. Its natural replacement is `AppCompatActivity`. To use it you need to add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

as dependency in your `build.gradle`.

`getSupportActionBar()` returns null if your theme is one without `ActionBar` . If you are using a theme with `ActionBar` or you are using the `ToolBar`, then you can ignore the warning. If you want to be sure check against NPE

```
 final ActionBar actionBar;
 if (getActivity() != null && (actionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar()) != null) {
       actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
 }
```

Comment: .getSupportActionBar() is always unresolved for me, even when changing over.

Comment: what you mean by *even when changing over* ?

Comment: Sorry. When updating my build gradle.

Comment: I also get this which prevents me from building: Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Comment: I suppose it's not syncing. All my resource values refuse to be resolved; rather, all my Rs are red.

Comment: is your sdk up-to-date? Open the android sdk manager and update it. If you were still using ActionBarActivity, probably you have a lot to catch up with

Comment: the version of appcompat that I copied/pasted is for sdk23.

Comment: Okay much, appreciated. This is all fairly new to me. Does my compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion have to change as well to reflect this?

Comment: If I were in you I would use the latest stable one. But yes they have to aligned

Comment: Hrm... Really not liking me today. ``Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.1.1'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.``

Comment: I am currently using    `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`

Comment: take your time to update everything you have to update through the AndroidSDKManager. It could take a while